Randomizing Object without changing every second. Geometry nodes
hope you're doing well!
I am currently facing a couple setbacks with using geometry nodes for the first time. I've used 2 tutorials in tandem to make the attached node setup.
The gist of it is, I need hexagon shapes with a specific material to scale from 0 to a certain number as the camera goes forward. This scene has been tracked in after effects and bought in blender. It does look good so far but the two issues are-

The object(hexagon) keeps changing to another one as soon as a new one pops in.
I need to tweak the geometry proximity node so that I can alter the distance once it passes through a tighter space.

Sorry if I am unable to explain that very well, I have attached a couple things to possibly further the explanation.





Your question needs a lot of detail.... How is a "mesh line" becoming an hexagonal shaped distribution? How are you assigning material? How is the material texture selected? So many things not shown that it's quite impossible to guess.

I suppose you have an object info node in the shader, taking a random from it. I guess you should assign this random to "instances" in the geometry nodes with "store named attribute" instead. And take this value in the shader from an attribute node.

Hi @DanielMöller, I apologize yes. The hexagons are modelled separately, there are 15 of them, each of which has a unique material. I added the collection that housed all 15 hexagons into the geometry node. So the object wasn't modelled within the geometry node stack. I first took all 15 hexagons and then using geometry node, I instanced it in a very large area so there were 100s of them. I then use the geometry proximity node inside the geometry node stack.

And I do apologize, I didn't quite get the second comment you mentioned.
If I need to give any more details, please let me know. Appreciate the help.

Maybe use the ID input instead of index ? I'm not sure but it may be temporarily consistent even if you add/remove geometry.

Hi, alright, I solved the first issue, it was as simple as just ticking the "Pick Instance" box in the Instance on Points nodes.
Now I just have to figure out the placement thing, it may be just as simple as scaling the proximity object.
